# how to make *.domain.com works in amazon ec2 running ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a domain running with amazon Route 53 on amazon instance. what I want is when I use the wildcard like this for example:
anything.domain.com
whatever.domain.com

currently  getting this error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Have you got a record of `*.example.com`?

Comment: yes I added the record with A type.

Comment: Do any other hosts resolve to it?

Comment: no there is no other host

Comment: And this is via HTTP?

Comment: https using cloudflare

Comment: also added the A record entry with server ip in cloud flare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS configuration (and Route 53) supports a `*` wildcard domain.

If you do this you will need to ensure that the target host can serve the domain. The error you're seeing is likely to be one of the following and not a DNS issue:

- The security group is not allowing inbound access to you on either port 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS).
- The service that should serving web traffic is not running, ensure the service is started. This includes ensuring the port that the service is trying to connect to is listened on.
- If you're using HTTPS ensure that it is a valid SSL, insecure SSLs will cause connection issues from applications which will reject the connection.

As you're using CloudFlare remember that this will sit in front of the host, its likely that it's trying to connect to HTTPS on your host.

Comment: if I add manual record of subdomain in cloudflare it works but * not working

Comment: I think I see the issues, https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017421192-Cloudflare-DNS-FAQ#CloudflareDNSFAQ-DoesCloudflaresupportwildcardDNSentries. If you're not paying for CloudFlare you don't get the free HTTPS (as it does not proxy through). Are you running HTTPS on your ec2 host?

Comment: Can you connect directly on the EC2 host using HTTPS (use the value you put into your DNS configuration)

Comment: no i cannot access using https directly with ec2 dns or ip

Comment: OK, can you confirm that you have port 443 open in security group and that you have a host on your server listening on 443 serving HTTPS?

Comment: You’ll want to add this :)

Comment: its the ssl issue now working on http with subdomain and https on main domain

Comment: If its self-signed you will see a certificate issue for the SSL, you would need to either purchase a SSL or use a free service like certbot :)